# PIPESTATUS variable does not return all the exit codes after running a pipeline

Tags: arrays, bash, pipestatus

I am using the PIPESTATUS variable to access all the exit codes of the pipeline: `echo "hello" | wc -w`. Now since the commands run with success, the PIPESTATUS array returns me 0 0 when I access using `echo ${PIPESTATUS[*]}` immediately after running the pipeline either in script or terminal.
However, when I try to print them separately by using the following codes:

```
echo "${PIPESTATUS[0]}" # it prints the output 0
echo "${PIPESTATUS[1]}" # doesn't print anything, blank terminal
```

The whole code is:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hello" | wc -w
echo "${PIPESTATUS[0]}"
echo "${PIPESTATUS[1]}"
```

how to solve this? And why it's not possible to access elements in such a way. It's an array so it should be possible.
Does the PIPESTATUS have anything to do with being volatile or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what the manual says:

> **PIPESTATUS**
>
> An array variable containing a list of exit status values from the processes in the most-recently-executed foreground pipeline (which may contain only a single command).

The contents of `PIPESTATUS` change after every pipeline. `echo "${PIPESTATUS[0]}"` is a pipeline too, so `PIPESTATUS` is populated with its exit status before `echo "${PIPESTATUS[1]}"` is executed. But since the previous pipeline contains only one command, `PIPESTATUS[1]` is rendered empty, hence the empty output.

You're looking for something like this:

```
echo "hello" | wc -w
status=("${PIPESTATUS[@]}")
echo "${status[0]}"
echo "${status[1]}"
```

Comment: how echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]} is a pipeline too ?? can you explain ?

Comment: @masrur It's a pipeline with only one command. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html and let me know if you need further clarification.

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance. It was an enlightenment